# How to create a MongoDB DAO layer like JPA using the entity manager does to facilitate all other DAO class in term of design?

Tags: java, mongodb, servlets, design-patterns

Knowing that there are some frameworks to do it in real-world situation. As I learning from scratch, I wonder is that possible to create pure *MongoDB DAO* as a layer on top of the `Service` class to do `CRUD` operation that also facilitate other DAO use it?

For example, below is my Generic DAO class to operate CRUD process.

```
public interface IGenericDAO<T> {
    public T create(T t);

    public T update(T t);

    public T get(Object id);

    public void delete(Object id);

    public List<T> listAll();

    public Long count();

}
```

Then, DAO class should implements its operations

```
public class UserDAO implements IGenericDAO<User> {

    MongoDatabase database = dBUtils.getMongoDB();
    MongoCollection <Document> userTbl = database.getCollection("User");

    public UserDAO() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        return user;
        
    }
// other CURD below
}
```

User Service class

```
public class UserService {

    private UserDAO userDAO;   

    public UserService() {
    }


    public void listUser() {

        // need to test
        List<User> listUsers = userDAO.listAll();

    }

    public void create(User user) {

        // this what I want to see. user is saved to db here
        try {
            MongoDatabase database = dBUtils.getMongoDB();
            assert mdb != null;

            // create or get collection
            MongoCollection<User> userTbl = database.getCollection("Users", User.class);              

            User userDoc = new User();

            userTbl.insertOne(userDoc);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Having said that, I want to put MongoDB "layer" between the DAO and Service class to do the CRUD operation. I wonder is it necessary, otherwise, how to do it to help the `UserService` with `UserDAO` class?

Comment: I could use morphia, but likely I have limited knowledge and want to try to learn pure MongoDB to do CRUD shown on a browser first.